# Anaconda 3 Spyder Version 4.0.1 corrupted, cant install v4.1.3 completely

Tags: anaconda, spyder

On my MacBook Pro, I used Anaconda Spyder 4.0.1 successfully for 6 weeks. But this week it started producing extraneous plots and printouts, even after removing all variables, Restarting the kernel and restarting Spyder. It was so bad I couldn’t find my real outputs.

This happened despite the fact that my python 3 script finished execution. With no error exceptions

I first tried upgrading Spyder, since it said version 4.1.3 was available and suggested i should try it I did this successfully in terminal with CondA install Spyder 4.1.3. But this did not update the version available from Anaconda navigator.

So I clean unininstalled Anaconda 3 and reinstalled from new download, but got Spyder 4.0.1 again, with the very same results

This loop does not converge, so I am dead in the water.

Answer (score 0):

I could not update Spyder from version 4.0.1 either (although I tried via the Anaconda GUI, not via terminal).
When I tried 'conda update --all' via terminal it worked. I did get a message that anaconda itself needed to be downgraded.